# How to allign login form fields to same row?

Tags: css, wordpress, widget, styling

I want to allign login fields in my [form](http://definitiv.cz/) to be in the same row like is [here](https://www.betrush.com/verified/). I tryed some CSS codes, but that dont align in way i like.

My login form:

[image]

How i want to make it:

[image]

This is CSS for that part:

```
.log_forms input[type=text], input[type=password] {
margin: 10px 0 20px;
width: 99%;
padding: 7px 0 7px 4px;
border: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<div>` lacks a `width`. Please add this in the CSS:

```css
.log-form-group {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 48%;
}
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

**Updated**

This is the extra CSS you need:

```css
.log_forms input[type=text], input[type=password] {width: 95% !important;}
.log-form-group {width: 32%;}
```

And you get this:

[image: preview]

Comment: Login button is still in second row. How to move in one line? Your answer is very usefull.

Comment: @DrMTR Sure, you may give smaller width, may be 30% for accommodating three in a row?

Comment: Yes can be. Can you modify your asnwer to fit all 3 in one row pls?

Comment: @DrMTR Check out the answer bro... Added full details of what code needs to be added, etc...

Comment: Many thanks bro, that makes the job. Will accept your answer for some minute as valid.

Comment: @DrMTR Thanks man... Please refresh and see the answer once... `:)`

Comment: I dont know what to say more. Thanks you so much ! You are Genius. :)

Comment: @DrMTR No worries bro... You are at the right place... In the right hands... Ha ha... Thanks and welcome in advance! `:)`